# The email or password is incorrect

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-так-задумано, локализация, регистрация

### 1. Описание

В поездке пытался [**залогиниться**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/login) в Stack Overflow на русском или любом другом сайте сети Stack Exchange. Если совершал ошибку, получал сообщение:

> The email or password is incorrect

[image: Email or password]

---

---

### 2. Суть проблемы

Пользовательнице/пользователю остаётся догадываться, совершена ли ошибка в адресе электронной почте или пароле. У меня, например, несколько электронных ящиков и используемых паролей. На подбор правильной комбинации ушло много времени.

---

---

### 3. Предложение

Лучше, если будет определённо указано, совершена ли ошибка в email или пароле, без «или». Примеры сообщений с других сайтов:

- Данный e-mail не зарегистрирован на сайте,
- Неверный пароль.

Ну и сообщения на русском, а не английском, не помешали бы.

Спасибо.

Comment: [tag:так-задумано]

Comment: вы предлагаете дать возможность любому пробивать email на факт регистрации. это несекьюрно :)

Comment: @PashaPash, допустим, что возможность узнать, в пароле или email совершена ошибка при входе, будет введена. Насколько повысится уязвимость аккаунта? Столь ли серьёзная проблема будет создана? Спасибо.

Comment: @PashaPash Пожалуйста прочтите: личное обращение основателя ---Википедии Джимми Уэйлса--- стековерфлоу Джеффа Этвуда https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-god-login/#telltheuserwhentheiremaildoesntexist . Я уж молчу о том, что у доброй половины пользователей этот имейл светится в гит-коммитах

Comment: @Etki у 95% пользователей основной емейл один, и они не тупят на логине.

Comment: @PashaPash и что, от этого что-то поменялось?

Comment: @СашаЧерных на самом деле вариантов ошибки больше чем два. например, пользователь есть, но пароля нет - он входил через гугл. или пользователь есть, email есть, но конкретно для этого email пароль не подходит. но подходит для другого email у этого же пользователя (например, у вас аж 3 email в профиле привязано). пускать?

Comment: @Etki да, ес-но поменялось - если мне написало "неправильный Email или пароль" - то я точно знаю что неправильный именно пароль.

Comment: @PashaPash нет, потому что я пользователь с десятком имейлов

Comment: @Etki ну значит вам и Саше не повезло

Comment: @PashaPash я ей-богу не понимаю ни аргументов "не повезло", ни влияния процента пользующихся одним имейлом против остальных, ни откуда он взят (более того, мой внутренний диванный статист уверен, что таких людей не больше 30%); "несекьюрность" этого подхода аналогична несекьюрности публичного доступа к алгоритму мд5, с помощью которого можно подобрать оригинал от хэша, а эффективность его использования можно сравнить только с анекдотом про рядовых, копающих яму ломом. Тот же гитхаб прямо в открытую хостит сотни имейлов, а спам мне падал всего один раз за всю жизнь.

Comment: Я просто не вижу здесь иной аргументации, нежели "я так привык, и мне кажется, что это норм" - без какого-либо рассмотрения альтернатив - и меня это задевает. Прямо выше лежит ссылка от этвуда, который прямо говорит о своем опыте и о том, что таких людей полно, а фрустрация от забытого логина просто бесконечна.

Comment: @Etki причем тут открытось емейла и спам? Считается (кем-то?) что *нехорошо* позволять кому угодно проверять факт регистрации конкретного email на конкретном ресурсе. Хотя бы потому, что подобрать рабочую пару email и пароль труднее, чем подобрать брутфорсом или по словарю только пароль.

Comment: в том и дело, что никто не знает, кем считается. *просто принято*, ну и все тут.

Comment: @Etki если Этвуд так за хороший логин ратует - чего он не сделает его как положено *на своих сайтах*?

Comment: @PashaPash я дал вам ссылку, где он пишет, что добавил его в discourse, которым он занимается (или занимался в то время) как основным проектом. Я ей-богу не понимаю этого вопроса, овтет прямо там в тексте.

Comment: @Etki ну как бы не то чтобы принято - часть про перебор email + пароля vs перебор просто пароля вроде как очевидна, нет?

Comment: @Etki я вот только что проверил - discourse выдает ошибку "Incorrect username, email or password". так что вопрос "а почему он у себя так не сделает" - более чем актуален

Comment: @PashaPash насчет выяснения регистрации: а что если попробовать зарегаться с мылом, которое уже зарегано, не будет ли это как раз проверкой факта регистрации?

Comment: @alexolut показывает "The email address you have used is already registered. However, our automatic log in attempt has failed.".

Comment: @NickVolynkin что нужно сделать для получения такого результата?

Comment: @alexolut, в форме регистрации ввести существующий email с рандомным паролем и подтвердить.

Comment: @Qwertiy не считая проблемы с подчеркиванием вкладки "регистрация" всё вроде бы [нормально](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYJQE.png).

Comment: @alexolut, вроде бы да.

Comment: @Qwertiy так о чем тогда речь?

Comment: @alexolut, я, видимо, просто твой вопрос не так понял.

Answer (score 4):

Выполнил перевод в [transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/85321174?key=2b1c7d763846d3fb7b8f4c1d0de939ac):

> Почта или пароль заданы неверно.

В чём конкретно ошибка пользователю знать не надо, т.к. это может быть потенциальный взломщик. Часто бывают пишут ещё что-то подобное: "Данная пара почта/пароль не является правильной".